# get_terms orderby name as numbers

Tags: sort, order, terms

I have a custom taxonomy filled with terms such as 'volume 1', 'volume 2', 'issue 1', 'issue 2', 'issue 10' and get_terms orderby name returns list as:
issue 1, issue 10, issue 2 though I need it to be issue 1, issue 2, issue 10

I tried searching wp.stackexchange and using my google-fu to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is very old but still answering for others who reach here.

Following is a very simple filter to sort the terms as numbers. You only need to set the variable `$taxonomy_to_sort` with `taxonomy slug` and place it in `functions.php` of your theme.

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', 'terms_order_as_number', 10,  3);

function terms_order_as_number($order_by, $args, $taxonomies){

    $taxonomy_to_sort = "numbers";

    if(in_array($taxonomy_to_sort, $taxonomies)){
        $order_by .=  " * 1";
    }

    return $order_by;
}
```

Comment: I would like to mention that this solution broke the `tax_query` arguments I tried to implement later. I went ahead and used a utility functions that returned all terms ordered with a `usort` custom function.

Answer (score 1):

There are many similar posts on the forum, if you look around.

You **do not have numbers**. Therefore you cannot sort numerically. You have to sort alphabetically and that will give you the pattern you see. I am honestly not even sure if [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) supports a numeric sort (at a glance I'd say it doesn't) since I doubt many terms are entirely made up of numbers .

You have a couple of options.

1. Write you own SQL query. I think, but I am not sure, you can do this
   in pure SQL but it would be tricky-- you'd have to [`substr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) the
   term name and sort on that. It would be hairy and probably not very efficient.
2. If you are pulling a few terms at a time, you could sort them in PHP
   before you display them. You'd have to do the same thing as in the
   SQL and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) the name, sort, and put it back together. Any pagination would be problematic with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Where's that problems root?

First, you're asking to sort by a part that is *inside* some string. This is **no native functionality in *any* programming language**.

Second, your actual problem is not "sorting by number", but the way you *constructed* those numbers. If you'd have known this issue in front (and taken it into account), you could've written a filter that would pad those zeros in front of your numbers.

### How to ignore the actual problem and work around it.

This doesn't really *fix* the problem, but as we (and maybe you too) don't know how many "issues" you might come up with (10, 1k, 100k?), we're just adding the sorting when displaying it. Here's a template tag for you to use:

```
function wpse80063_numsorted_issues()
{
    $terms  = get_terms( 'issues', array( /* of possible args */ );
    $digits = strlen( count( $terms ) );
    $sorted_terms = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        preg_match( "/\d+/", $term, $nr );
        $nr = sprintf( "%0{digits}d", $nr );
        // If the above line doesn't work, take this one:
        // $nr = str_pad( $nr, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $sorted_terms[ $nr ] = $term;
    }
    ! empty( $sorted_terms ) AND sort( $sorted_terms );

    return $sorted_terms;
}
```

Comment: _any_? http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: @nepykstu Aha... should be an answer then.

Comment: Here is the raw SQL method http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to get this to work,

With a great help from https://objectiv.co/taking-natural-sort-alphanumeric-wordpress-even/

```
add_filter('get_terms', 'sort_terms_naturally', 20, 3);

function sort_terms_naturally ( $terms, $taxonomies, $args ) {
    $taxonomy_to_sort = "pa_size";
    if(in_array($taxonomy_to_sort, $taxonomies) && count($taxonomies) == 1 ){ // just sort natuarly the terms in the sidebar
        $sort_terms = array();

        foreach($terms as $term) {
            $sort_terms[$term->name] = $term;
        }

        uksort( $sort_terms, 'strnatcmp');

        if ( strtolower($args['order']) == "desc" || true) $sort_terms = array_reverse($sort_terms);

        return $sort_terms;
    }
    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. Thanks!